# How do I use pax to extract to a specific directory

Tags: linux, pax

I am currently using `tar` to extract files...

```
tail -n+$ARCHIVE_START_LINE $archiveFilename | tar -xzm -C /
```

I need to use `pax` instead of `tar`, so something like ...

```
tail -n+$ARCHIVE_START_LINE $archiveFilename | gzip -d | pax -r
```

This extracts to the current directory. Is there a way to extract to a specific directory (root in my case)? (I have tried `...  pax -r > /` but that gave an error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is just to wrap `pax` in a subshell:

```
tail -n+$ARCHIVE_START_LINE $archiveFilename | gzip -d | ( cd / ; pax -r )
```